# aws ec2 instance status check interval less than minute

Tags: amazon-ec2, high-availability

Minimum value for EC2 instance StatusCheckFailed interval seems to be one minute. Is it possible to reduce this to 2 failures for 15 seconds?

We have a requirement to detect failures quickly in 10-15 seconds range. Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you intend to do once a failure is detected? What are you running on the instance and can it move to a serverless (Lambda) method instead of EC2?

Comment: I plan to restart the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can set the resolution of the status check to less than 1 minute. One potential workaround would be to implement a lambda function that essentially performs a status check (via your own code) on a more frequent time interval via a cron job.